# Item added to jquery autocomplete list can't be highlighted or selected

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, selection

I am using the following code to add an item "Other" to an autocomplete list:

```
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $('.ui-autocomplete').append('<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1"><strong>Other</strong></a></li>');
    },
```

The item "Other" appears at the end of every list given to user as response to what he types, but the item will not highlight when the mouse moves over it and does not get selected when clicked. What do I need to do to ensure it is highlighted and can be selected when clicked?

I am using Firebug to follow the code into my select function shown below:

```
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        if (ui.item) {
            var value = ui.item.type + ui.item.id;
            var name = ui.item.acronym;
            addContent(value, name);
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).val('');
        }
    },
```

When I click on any item other than "Other", the select function executes without error and the item clicked is processed properly. But when I click on the "Other" item, i get an error message "f.item" is null in jQuery UI 1.8.14min.js on line 322.

So in addition to adding the li element via the open function, I also need to add an object to something that maps to the li. Just how do i do that?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What makes the item highlight?

Comment: I really don't know how the autocomplete widget works internally, but items in an autocomplete dropdown list are highlighted when you drag your mouse over the item.

Comment: Can you see if a class is added on hover? Is this an autocomplete plugin?

Answer (score 0):

This JSFiddle shows it working just fine: [The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roafbq83/3/)

Is it possilbe that there's some other div / DOM object overlapping it at runtime?

```js
var test = function() {   
    
        $('.ui-autocomplete').append('<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1"><strong>Other</strong></a></li>');
    
}

test();
```

Comment: Yes, it does put the li element "Other" at the end of every dropdown list, butonce there, dragging the mouse over it does not cause it to be highlighted and clicking the item when the mouse is over it does not select it.

Comment: @FredLittle, What browser are you using? I am in Chrome on Windows, and I am able to highlight and select it perfectly fine.